# Best Method of Working With Number(s) Over 1*10^100000000

Tags: math, numbers, programming-languages

I am well aware this is a crazy thing to ask, but what method and or language should I look towards to work with numbers of over 1*10^100000000? I know doubles and such have much smaller limits in accuracy, but my purpose is to apply math such as division, addition, etc to these numbers.

Comment: Language choice is beyond the scope of this site. There are many languages that can handle big integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different languages use different library to support arbritrary-precision arithmetics. Most modern programming language offer support for it in one way or another.

Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Languages

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Or, like I did, to  vote to close.

Comment: @JanDvorak I have to wonder why you would want to close this excellent question. SO has become progressively more narrow-minded; it is lamentable, but it needn't be like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Typically there are separate packages for integers and for floats. Some languages have these built-in; for example Maxima [1] has both integers and floats. Some other languages (e.g. Common Lisp) have only integers built-in. For other languages such as C and C++, you can get libraries.

[1] http://maxima.sourceforge.net, http://sf.net/p/maxima